XSLT: sorting objects and preserving comments
I'm using a tool to convert game data to XML but one of said tool's quirks is that it outputs parent code objects alphanumerically instead of numerically, sample output with comments below:
<container format="RTPC" endian="Little">
    <object>
        <object name="root">
            <object name="0"><!-- disables input -->
                <value name="_class" type="string">CInputActionOverride</value>
                <value name="_class_hash" type="int">-1833934533</value>
                <value name="_object_id" type="objectid">26D7913A,0</value>
                <value name="action_list" type="string">Accelerate</value><!-- action name -->
                <value name="activate_event" type="vec_events">death_run_play_cutscene,0x0</value>
            </object>
            <object name="1">
                <value name="_class" type="string">CGameObjectList</value>
                <value name="_class_hash" type="int">-1531974803</value>
                <value name="_object_id" type="objectid">C51129BC,0</value><!-- spawn list ref -->
                <value name="name" type="string">SpawnedVehicleList</value>
                <value name="tags" type="vec_int"/>
            </object>
            <object name="10">
                <value name="_class" type="string">CNavMeshDynamicObstacle</value>
                <value name="_class_hash" type="int">838607288</value>
                <value name="_object_id" type="objectid">F96135EC,0</value>
                <value name="disable_event" type="vec_events"/>
                <value name="enable_event" type="vec_events"/>
                <value name="enabled_from_start" type="int">1</value>
            </object>
            <object name="100">
                <value name="_class" type="string">SAnimationLayerInfo</value>
                <value name="_class_hash" type="int">-786417417</value>
                <value name="_object_id" type="objectid">B2B5BF10,0</value>
                <value name="file" type="string">animations/characters/light_facelayer.al</value><!-- anim path -->
                <value name="layer_index" type="int">1</value>
                <value name="layer_name" type="string">Face</value>
                <value name="name" type="string">AnimationLayerInfoFace</value>
            </object>
            <object name="102">
                <value name="_class" type="string">CSpawnReferencePosition</value>
                <value name="_class_hash" type="int">-1429677905</value>
                <value name="_object_id" type="objectid">1958DDF6,0</value>
                <value name="keep_orientation" type="int">1</value>
                <value name="name" type="string">CSpawnReferencePosition</value>
                <value name="no_create_on_load" type="int">1</value>
                <value name="tags" type="vec_int"/>
            </object>
        </object>
    </object>
</container>

To address this sorting issue, I'm using this slightly modified XSL template that I found:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="object">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
                <xsl:sort select="@name" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

This template does the job but another issue I'm facing is that the transformation eats all comments [I'm lead to believe this is default behaviour] and my XSL knowledge is next to non-existent, meaning I'm having difficulty figuring out the code necessary to both sort code objects and keep all comments.

All the comments I see in your example input are children of the " numbered" object elements  the need to be sorted.
Assuming there are no comments that are children of the object whose name is root, you could solve your problem by slightly modifying your template so that instead of:
<xsl:template match="object">

it reads:
<xsl:template match="object[@name='root']">

Then only the children of the "root" object will be sorted, and everything else will be copied as is by the identity transform template.

using your answer, object sorting works correctly and comments carry over to a transformed document, but for some reason the comments get pushed to a new line rather than remaining where they are. additionally, object names and comments are indented all the way to the left.
object indentation is not an issue as such, but comments getting a newline "treatment" is a bit awkward

That's something that depends more on your processor's serializing algorithm than your XSLT code. See what happens if you add a <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> instruction to the top level of your stylesheet.

Or try indent="no".

effectively it's the same result; comments get pushed down to a new line. for context, [assuming it makes any difference] I'm using notepad++ with "XML tools" plugin.
edit: just saw your update - setting indent to "no" keeps comments where they should be but object's closing tag is now on the same line as the opening tag of the next one, eg. 

Which processor is that?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153

I'm sorry if this is frustrating but no matter where I put those two lines in the stylesheet, XML plugin says "the stylesheet is not valid, transformation aborted"

Try this stylesheet: https://file.io/6cbe5cJhQ4xH

version 1, vendor is Microsoft. the plugin's "about" box does say it's based on MSXML

I am afraid I can't help you with that processor. In general, XSLT offers limited control over the output's indentation - see, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/22529724/3016153. In the worst case, if you are unable to configure the processor, you can always strip all original white space, set indent to "no" and do your own indenting by adding individual whitespace text nodes where you want them. But that could be a lot of work.

stripping whitespace and disabling indent turns the whole file into a single line. not a big issue since I can just click "pretty print", same for any other type of wonky output. overall, your answer does exactly what I need - sorting objects AND keeping comments, so I reckon I could just do some post-transform regex on the comments. thank you for your time
